# Tmux + mutt not redrawing

Tags: macos, tmux, mutt

I've recently switched to mutt, but have been using tmux for a year or so now.

Mutt seems to have occasional issues redrawing, for example if I delete a bunch of email using `d` and then persist the changes using `$` the list of email doesn't update until I resize the terminal window.

I'm running:

- tmux 1.9a
- mutt 1.5.23
- iTerm2 2.0.0.20141103

I have also noticed redrawing issues using Vim under tmux (more infrequently) and the issue also persists when using the standard OSX terminal instead of iTerm2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, except I was using gnome-terminal.

Turns out that my TERM variable was set incorrectly (due to bad logic in my .bashrc).

```
$ TERM=xterm-256color
```

Setting `TERM=screen` or `TERM=screen-256color` solved this problem for me.

Testing:

```
TERM=screen-256color mutt
```

Making the changes persistent

~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

~/.bashrc

```
TERM='screen-256color'
```

However, changing TERM in .bashrc might not be the best idea. If you ever use a terminal that isn't xterm compatible you will likely run into problems.

If $TERM != screen or screen-256 inside of tmux, I would recommend figuring out what is changing it.

Comment: That's it! thanks pyther! for some reason I had `TERM=xterm-256color` in my .zshrc file